# When my car warms up the dash lights dim badly, what could be the cause?

Tags: electrical, vw, jetta

My son has a 2005 VW Jetta.  It starts right up and drives good but when the car warms up the dash lights dim and it starts running differently.  He is afraid to drive too far because once it left him stranded and didnt start back up and we went and jumped it and then it started.  Does anyone know why this is happending?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What do you mean by runs differently? Is the alternator or check engine light coming on?